# How to open link in the array in python

Tags: python, excel

```
df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", sheet_name = "Sheet1")
file_list = []
file_list.append(df)

driver.get(file_list)
```

the result when I `print(df)`

[image]

I tried to open excel file in the array called 'file_list' but it didn't work

Can you please give some helpful tips on how to perform this job

cheers

Comment: Can you elaborate on "failing the job"? What is the error?

Comment: I meant I tried the code which what I've just typed on the board, but it didn't work out

Comment: You're loading the Excel file in the dataframe named `df` and then you put the dataframe (as a whole) in a list - the list only contains one element, the dataframe. You probably want to access the rows and columns of the dataframe, e.g. `df[0][0]` for the top-leftmost cell, assuming your data has no headers and you would need to pass `header = None` in the `read_excel` call - if your data does have headers, it would be `df['col_name'][0]` for the first value in that column

Comment: To make it easier for people to answer your question, it would be good if you `print(df)` and share at least the first few lines of the result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've just added what you've said. cheers